# Seeking the right pattern to apply same rules to different data sets

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

Suppose you have a `List<Elements>` in memory and a `List<Files>`, each of which is a serialized representation of `List<Elements>`

The goal is to perform the same algorithm against each of the elements.

Lets say the job is to count elements

```
int i = 0;
for (Element e : list) {
       ++i;
}

for (File f : directory()) {
    for (Element e : listWeSomehowGetFromTheFile) {
           ++i;
    }
}
```

Can this be further abstracted somehow? Essentially, algorithm is identical (`++i`). Is there a way to clean this up?

I certainly can have it's own class `Counter(List<Element>)`, that has `count ()` method that runs the algo on the list. This way we can:

```
 i+=Counter.count(list);
 for (File f : directory()) {
   i+=Counter.count(listWeSomehowGetFromTheFile);
 }
```

But even this seems like it can be improved.

For the purposes of this example, lets assume that all operations (a bunch of them) will be performed on list in memory and a list coming from the same files in same directories. The only thing that would change is the algo.

What pattern would fit best to handle something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is quite popular when you want to do something to each item in a collection.

The visitor pattern is also good because it allows you to expand the calculations you can perform without rewriting the class on which visitors operate.

If you don't need to follow  a formal pattern exactly,

1) define an interface like `Operation` with a method `calculate` that takes an element and operates.
2) You calculation is an implementation of `Operation`.
3) Loop over your elements, passing the elements to your operation implementation.

If the results of calculate are cumulative (depend on previous calculate invocations against other elements), you can modify `calculate` to take an object that contains the state of the calculation, and then when `calculate` is fired against an element, you update the state.  You keep passing the same state object to every calculate invocation.

As an outline (this wont compile):

```
public Interface Operation {
   // don't necessarily need state
   public void calculate (Element e, State state);
}

CountOp extends Operation {
   count = 0;

   public void calculate(Element e, State state){
      // not using element or state because this is so simple....
      count++;
   }
}

Operation op = new CountOp();
State state = new SomeStateImpl();
for (File f : directory()) {
    for (Element e : listWeSomehowGetFromTheFile) {
          op.calculate(e, state);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up implementing something very close to this before i looked at the answer. Very neat to get a confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

i may be misunderstanding, but the way i would approach this is to write the function in terms of a (lazy) sequence - it's easy to make both a list and data from a file into a lazy sequence of values.

in more practical terms, lazy streams in java are usually implemented as iterables (or iterators, if you don't need to restart), and the guava library has many [utilities](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html) for working with these.

this assumes that elements are of the same type.  the visitor pattern is more suited for when the data structure you are processing has different types (the visitor is where you do type based dispatch; that's not necessary for a single type, so the visitor pattern for a single type is equivalent to generating a stream of data - in that case it's simpler to use existing iterators).